# Windows Phone Call SMS Notification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want my app to know if there are any missed calls or unread sms in the phone.
Is this possible in Windows Phone 8?
 How?

I wish to connect to a Bluetooth device which has a led attached and make it blink if there are notifications.

The application will run in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no API for that.

It might be added in future versions of the system:
[WPDev Feedback: Allow readonly access to Call History and Text History](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1905841-please-allow-readonly-access-to-call-history-and)

Answer (score 0):

With UWP (Universal Windows Platform, AKA Windows 10), you now have increased access to SMS (send and receive) through Windows.Devices.SMS. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive)

NOTE: You will have to request special access permissions, but it isn't as restricted as it was before.